# Passing Keyword Argument to Python Class (for Tweepy Streamer)

Tags: python, csv, tweepy

### Current State

I have working implementation of the [Tweepy Twitter Streamer](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html) that writes tweets to a CSV.

This works fine.

---

### Problem: CSV Name is Hardcoded in Python Class

If I were dealing with simple functions, I could easily resolve this. Being somewhat new to Python classes, I am struggling.

I have tried using the `def __init__(self, keyword):` syntax inside the class. This seems to work if I treat the class as a standard object. It breaks the code if I try to implement Tweepy. My guess is that I have either not attempted this correctly and/or the Tweepy StreamListener class is not designed to accept keyword arguments.

---

#### Below is the code (with hardcoded filenames) that successfully works:

*I have commented out the broken lines of my attempt to pass keywords*

```
import csv
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#Insert Your Twitter Credentials Here
from mycredentials import *

#Set Authorization
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)



class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    #Broken Attempt
    #def __init__(self, keyword):
    #    self.keyword = keyword

    def start_csv():
        #Broken Attempt
        #filename = str(self.keyword)+".csv"
        #with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        with open('Clinton.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["DATE", "AUTHOR", "TWEET"])


    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            #Broken Attempt
            #filename = str(self.keyword)+".csv"
            #with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            with open('Clinton.csv', 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                
                #Tweet Content
                author = str(status.author.screen_name.encode('utf-8'))
                date = str(status.created_at)
                tweet = str(status.text.encode('utf-8'))
                
                print(date, tweet)
                writer.writerow([date, author, tweet])

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)


#Broken Attempt
#twitterStream = Stream(auth, TwitterListener("test"))

#Works
twitterStream = Stream(auth, TwitterListener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['#Clinton'])
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add what exactly do you mean by "broken" ? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 0):

When you override the `__init__` method of a class, you need to call the superclass's `__init__` method.

Your `__init__` method should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, keyword):
    super(TwitterListener, self).__init__()

    # Your code here
    self.keyword = keyword
```